# DataInputStream.readFully()?

Tags: java, input, stream, applet

I am working on an applet and it has to load files to a cache and I have got the downloading of the cache and unzipping down pat but now when I create the inputdatastream to read the cache I get an `EOFException`.

I thought okay I'll surround it with a `try catch` and that is what I did but then when the client went to use the cache file it got an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` and stopped on the first loading. I am beginning to believe that `DataInputStream.readFully();` is reaching the end of the file because it is not able to see this.

I can run this applet fine from eclipse/desktop and it downloads the cache and loads everything up so that is what leading me to think that the cache cannot be reached by the applet. I am running the applet with a simple `<applet></applet>` HTML file setup. I have tried setting the manifest with `Permissions: all-permissions` but I still get the same issue. I am self signing the applet but I can not get it to run remotely.

I have also tried to set a .policy with grant `java.security.AllPermissions`. I might have missed something trying this so if you have any tips that would be appreciated. Been researching for days and have not been able to find a solution. Hope you all know a quick solution, I bet I am missing something.

```
    java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at client.streamLoaderForName(client.java:5495)
    at client.startUp(client.java:10206)
    at RSApplet.run(RSApplet.java:84)
    at client.run(client.java:6740)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error: loaderror Requesting title screen 25
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at Stream.readUnsignedWord(Stream.java:135)
    at StreamLoader.<init>(StreamLoader.java:21)
    at client.streamLoaderForName(client.java:5577)
    at client.startUp(client.java:10206)
    at RSApplet.run(RSApplet.java:84)
    at client.run(client.java:6740)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    <center>
<applet name="Inspiration" width="765" height="503" archive="WC.jar" code="client.class">
<param name="java_arguments", value="-Xmx1024m">
</applet>
<center>
```

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: Have you digitally singed the applet?  Are you prompted to accept the digitally singed code?  I expect a lot of this comes down to the fact that your applet is not trusted.  Note also that adjusting policy files is not something that is useful at time of deployment.  Ignore it.

Comment: Other tips:  1) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: @Andrew, I have digitally signed the app, and it does prompt me to accept when the applet runs. How do I configured to show for applets and JWS?

Comment: I enabled the java console, that is my stracktrace for it above.  No issues running locally but that is what I get running it off a html file.

Comment: Check the post now.  Fixed to your liking, thanks for the formatting help!

Comment: OK, from that, it seems it is not security or the digital signatures that is the problem.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - if the input file is put on the run-time class-path of the applet, or is otherwise accessible relative to the code or document base of the applet, it would be much simpler to read it direct from there, and it can be done in a sand-box.  I'm not sure why you are going to all this trouble when Sun/Oracle have gone to considerable effort to provide in-built caching, combined with lazy downloads.  ..

Comment: .. It just seems like a lot of complication only to end up in this apparent mess.

Comment: Do you have any explanation why it would run locally but not in HTML?  Doesn't make much to me if the cache is the issue.

Comment: *"any explanation why it would run locally but not in HTML?"*  It could be down to a number of reasons.  The most likely is that the class-path is subtly different between the two.  Honestly though, I think it is counter-productive to to test applets 'locally'.  The conditions change between that and deployment, especially when it is being launched by an IDE.  I recommend *instead* to set up a local server, and always test it coming from that.  It provides a more realistic and reproducible result.

Comment: That's what I have been doing with WAMP server and still no luck.  So is there anywhere I can read to load a cache in a better way than looking in the User.home of the persons computer.  Thanks.

Comment: *"So is there anywhere I can read to load a cache"*  Use the standard applet methods to locate resources on the class-path, then load them by URL.  If the Jar is not cached, it will be downloaded and cached, if it is cached, the JRE will use the local copy.  Deploy the applet using JWS and it is possible to flag the data as 'lazy download', otherwise it will be cached immediately on applet load.  I strongly suggest you abandoned all this 'cleverness' and get it working using the standard mechanisms.  I expect once you do, you'll see it not only works, but works better than you expect.